# how to stop django autoreload without comman line argumer "--noreload"

Tags: python, django, cpanel, scheduling, apscheduler

I have developer a django app with the apscheduler and the scheduler runs twice whenever I don't use the "--noreload" command line argument with it. It was fine until I had it running on my local machine but after running it in the cpanel I don't understand how to stop the autoreloader since I can't enter a command line argument there. Please let me know how i can stop this from happening.

Comment: How did you configure the cpanel to run the scheduler right now?

Comment: I did not configure the cpanel. I used apscheduler to create a job and ran the job inside the ready function in the AppConfig classs inside my app